# Probability of getting any number if I roll the die 4 times.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, dice

We have a question to investigate any game between two players that have dice, when the dice are rolled $4$ times what is the probability of getting any number say $4$ or $5$.. note that the highest number is taken. So if a player gets $1,1,1,4$ or $1,2,5,3$ the highest number is taken to go against the other player. So what is the probability of getting the highest number as $1$ which is $1/1296$ and $2$ is $15/1296$, 3 is $56/1296$ but I can't seem to figure out a pattern or to create an equation to get the rest of the probability.

Comment: Do you mean that only one of the highest number is taken?  what about 1,1,5,5,5.  Would then the three 5's be taken?  Also, have you considered 1,1,1,1,1?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $N$ denote that number. Surely one can compute $\mathbb P(N\leqslant n)$ for each $1\leqslant n\leqslant6$, right? Then, $\mathbb P(N=n)=\mathbb P(N\leqslant n)-\mathbb P(N\leqslant n-1)$.